# errors and warnings in a function in C

Tags: c

my warnings and errors, I need to fix the errors:

```
exercici17b.c: In function ‘main’:
exercici17b.c:16:1: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘imprimeixvector’
 imprimeixvector(res[5], resu, mat[3][3], vect[3]);
 ^
exercici17b.c:4:5: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
 int imprimeixvector(double res[5], double resu, double mat[3][3], double vect[3]);
     ^
exercici17b.c:16:1: error: incompatible type for argument 3 of ‘imprimeixvector’
 imprimeixvector(res[5], resu, mat[3][3], vect[3]);
 ^
exercici17b.c:4:5: note: expected ‘double (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘double’
 int imprimeixvector(double res[5], double resu, double mat[3][3], double vect[3]);
     ^
exercici17b.c:16:1: error: incompatible type for argument 4 of ‘imprimeixvector’
 imprimeixvector(res[5], resu, mat[3][3], vect[3]);
 ^
exercici17b.c:4:5: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
 int imprimeixvector(double res[5], double resu, double mat[3][3], double vect[3]);
     ^
exercici17b.c: In function ‘imprimeixvector’:
exercici17b.c:48:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

my code is this one:
The code has to multiply the matrix by the vector and give the result as another vector, and I have an error in the function with the type of arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void imprimeixvector(double, double, double, double);

int main()
{
  double res[5], resu=0;
  double vect[3]={1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
  double mat[3][3]={
              {1., 1., 0.},
              {0., 1., 1.},
              {1., 0., 1.}      //matriu 3x3
            };

imprimeixvector(res[0], resu, mat[0][0], vect[0]);

printf("\n");
  return 0;
}


void imprimeixvector(double res[5], double resu, double mat[3][3], double vect[3])
{
  int i, j;
  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      res[i]=vect[j]*mat[i][j];
      resu=resu+res[i]; 
    }
  printf("%d,", (int) resu);
  resu=0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
void imprimeixvector(double, double, double, double);
```

with

```
void imprimeixvector(double res[5], double resu, double mat[3][3], double vect[3]);
```

in the declaration

And then call the function properly in main with

```
imprimeixvector(res, resu, mat, vect);
```

Comment: Thanks for everything!